# Value cannot be null. Parameter name: extent

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using EF6 code first to create my db. Everything was working well last night, now when i run update-database command, I get the following exception:

```
PM> update-database
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: extent
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.Check.NotNull[T](T value, String parameterName)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.StorageEntitySetMapping..ctor(EntitySet extent, StorageEntityContainerMapping entityContainerMapping)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.DbDatabaseMappingExtensions.AddEntitySetMapping(DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping, EntitySet entitySet)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.Services.TableMappingGenerator.Generate(EntityType entityType, DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.Services.DatabaseMappingGenerator.GenerateEntityTypes(DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.Services.DatabaseMappingGenerator.Generate(EdmModel conceptualModel)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbProviderInfo providerInfo)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_CodeFirstModel()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.EdmxWriter.WriteEdmx(DbContext context, XmlWriter writer)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbContextExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetModel>b__0(XmlWriter w)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbContextExtensions.GetModel(Action`1 writeXml)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbContextExtensions.GetModel(DbContext context)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration, DbContext usersContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.GetMigrator()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.Run()
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Update(String targetMigration, Boolean force)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: extent
```

Here is the Context Class

```
public class WheelTrackDb : DbContext
{
    public WheelTrackDb(): base("DefaultConnection"){ }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Driver>()
            .HasRequired(d => d.Vehicle)
            .WithOptional(v => v.Driver)
            .Map(m => m.MapKey("VehicleId"));

        modelBuilder.Entity<TransactionLog>()
           .HasRequired(t => t.Acceptor)
           .WithMany()
           .HasForeignKey(t => t.AcceptorId)
           .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<TransactionLog>()
           .HasRequired(t => t.Donor)
           .WithMany()
           .HasForeignKey(t => t.DonorId)
           .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Violation>()
            .HasRequired(v => v.GSMDeviceLog)
            .WithMany(g => g.Violations)
            .HasForeignKey(v => v.GSMDeviceLogId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<RouteFence>().Ignore(r => r.PolygonVertices);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Vehicle>()
            .HasRequired(v => v.License)
            .WithRequiredPrincipal();

        modelBuilder.Entity<MessageCounter>()
            .HasRequired(m => m.License)
            .WithOptional(l => l.MessageCounter)
            .Map(m => m.MapKey("LicenseId"));

        modelBuilder.Entity<GSMDeviceLog>()
            .HasRequired(g => g.Vehicle)
            .WithMany(t => t.GsmDeviceLogs);

    }

    public DbSet<UserInfo> UserInfos{ get; set; }
    public DbSet<TransactionLog> TransactionLogs{ get; set; }
    public DbSet<Driver> Drivers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Vehicle> Vehicles{ get; set; }
    public DbSet<VehicleGroup> VehicleGroups { get; set; }
    public DbSet<License> Licenses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Policy> Policys { get; set; }
    public DbSet<GSMDeviceLog> GSMDeviceLogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<MessageCounter> MessageCounters { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Violation> Violations { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OwnershipPaper> OwnershipPapers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Subscriber> Subscribers { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the Configuration:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<WheelTrack.Models.WheelTrackDb>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    }


    protected override void Seed(WheelTrack.Models.WheelTrackDb context)
    {

    }
}
```

I've searched internet and found that I should only have properties in my context class. And I checked thrice, it only has dbset properties. I'm unable to figure out what has happened. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How does your context class look, and how does the entity look which you modified last?

Comment: Please, post your `DbModelBuilder` configuration. Seems like some relation option is not set

Comment: Please see the edit. Also, I tried commenting the Fluent API code. But again no success.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Found the problem. Actually, I had a `HttpPostedFileBase` property in the UserInfo model which the EF could not bind to the database column.

Putting a not-mapped attribute over it made it work.

```
    [NotMapped]
    public HttpPostedFileBase Photo { get; set; }
```

So, for others who get this issue make sure two things:

1. Your context should always contain DbSets properties. For example -

   `public DbSet<Policy> Policies { get; set; }`
2. There should not be a type in your model classes that EF cannot bind to a database column.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Happened to me by trying to create a column based on ´System.IO.Stream´ when I should be using ´byte[]´

Comment: Thank you for this answer, specifically #2. Had a class with a MD5 property, been searching for days as to why this was breaking.

Comment: I had the same problem, after looking through all the entities I couldn't find any of the mentioned problems. Then I restarted Visual Studio Express 2012, and that solved the problem? :)