# Add-Migration Value cannot be null. Parameter name: language

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-migrations

I am trying to create a new migration but I get an System.ArgumentNullException
saying:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: language
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Utilities.Check.NotNull[T](T value, 
    String parameterName)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations..ctor
    (IOperationReporter reporter, Assembly assembly, Assembly 
    startupAssembly, String projectDir, String rootNamespace, String 
    language)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<.ct
    or>b__4()
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.LazyRef`1.get_Value()
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: language
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error with Entity Framework add-migration: "value cannot be null"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23735180/error-with-entity-framework-add-migration-value-cannot-be-null)

Comment: They are not the same

Comment: provide your model that you are adding

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's related to the EF Core not EF6, it looks like there is a bug in the 2.1.0.preview1-final version.

> - Check the version you are running with dotnet ef --version
> - Downgrade to the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design 2.0.1 version.

Comment: Cheers, been scratching my head for a while on this one.

Answer (score 10):

This is issue [#11075](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/11075). The version of your tool doesn't match the version of your runtime. Ensure you've updated every Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore package to 2.1.0-preview1-final.

Comment: Possibly a different code path for scaffolding vs. migrations?   I was hitting the error while doing a db migration.  Just saying for me the problem appears to be from a bug introduced in the 2.1.0 Final.  Downgrading to 2.0.1 will fixed my issue with migration. 
Added a detailed note with repro steps in the 11075 issue.

Comment: For me the not updated package was the <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.1.0-preview1-final" /> inside csproj

Comment: @animalitomaquina - yup this was it for me as well. Thanks! I need this version for now, because v2.0.2 doesn't support Ambient Transactions.

Comment: Thanks, this even was the case for EF6 but helped me as soon as I updated all the projects references to EF to latest version (as of now it is 6.4.4)

Answer (score 4):

If it is `EF 6.x.x`, then use `VS2019`.

Ref: https://github.com/dotnet/ef6/issues/1870

Answer (score 0):

For EF Core for .NET Core 2.0.1 in VS 2017 Version 15.7.1, I removed DotNetCliToolReference element from my project file.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug.
I'm using EF Core 2.2.4, i'm trying to rollback a migration with:

```
migrationBuilder.DropIndex(name: "myIndexName");
```

This was auto-generated for me by EF.
The method signature says name is the only required parameter (there's 2 optional ones after).
When i run this i get this:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: name
```

but if i add a second parameter for the table name it works:

```
migrationBuilder.DropIndex(
                name: "myIndexName",
                table: "myTableName");
```